# Remove all classes from multiple object when pressing a reset button

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello I got a question resetting all the classes when pressing a button. I have the following HTML setup:

```
<a class="test testclass">Test 1</a>
<a class="test testclass">Test 2</a>
<a class="test testclass">Test 3</a>

<a class="reset_all_classes">RESET ME</a>
```

With the following jQuery:

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('testclass testclass-active');
})

// Reset by removing all the testclass-active on all the <a>
$('.reset_all_classes').click(function(){
    $('.test').toggleClass('testclass-active testclass');
})
```

Whenever I press a hyperlink containing the class `test` then the class: `testclass` will be changed in `testclass-active`.  The problem lies within if you selected for example test 1 and test 3. Both will have the `testclass-active` then whenever I press the reset button all those hyperlinks will return to their default state: `testclass`. But in contrast button 2 will get the `testclass-active`

So I was wondering how could I achieve the situation where the buttons: test1 and test3 have the class `testclass-active`and whenever I press the reset button all the buttons return to their default class: `testclass`.

[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/rypbjs91/)

Comment: Does toggleclass really fit? It means that, if an object does NOT have the class, it's added... I'd use "removeClass" instead (in the reset part only). Btw you should use ".on" event handlers (like $(document).on('click','item',func(){})...

Comment: Thanks for you response? Could please elaborate on why using '.on' event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem with your code**

When ever you are clicking the element the classes will be changed. While you are resetting as per your code it is toggling. So it wont go to initial state.

**Solution**

> Instead to `toggleClass()` I used `removeClass()` and `addClass()` to make the elements to initial state.

```
$('.reset_all_classes').click(function(){
    $('.test').removeClass('testclass-active').addClass('testclass');
})
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/rypbjs91/2/)**

Comment: You beat me to it :(

Comment: Ha ha.. Sometimes it happens `:)`

Comment: sad :( type faster next time for us :(

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RinoRaj! This exactly what I want. Still it feels like sort of toggling if  you remove and add a class haha. I will accept your answer when the time limit is over ;)

Comment: @Rotan075 Ok.. Glad to hear that it helped. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.test').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('testclass testclass-active');
})

// Reset by removing all the testclass-active on all the <a>
$('.reset_all_classes').click(function() {
  $('.test').removeClass("testclass-active").addClass("testclass");
})
```

```css
.testclass,
.reset_all_classes,
.testclass-active {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.testclass-active {
  background-color: green;
}
.reset_all_classes {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test testclass">Test 1</a>
<a class="test testclass">Test 2</a>
<a class="test testclass">Test 3</a>

<a class="reset_all_classes">RESET ME</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/guradio/rypbjs91/1/)

```
$('.reset_all_classes').click(function(){
    $('.test').removeClass('testclass-active').addClass('testclass');
})
```

Dont toggle just add class and remove class you know what to add and what to remove

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.test').click(function(){
 $(this).toggleClass('testclass testclass-active');
})
 
// Reset by removing all the testclass-active on all the <a>
$('.reset_all_classes').click(function(){
 $('.test').removeClass('testclass-active');
  $('.test').addClass('test testclass');
})
```

```css
.testclass, .reset_all_classes, .testclass-active{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin:20px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

.testclass-active{
  background-color:green;
}

.reset_all_classes{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="test testclass">Test 1</a>
<a class="test testclass">Test 2</a>
<a class="test testclass">Test 3</a>

<a class="reset_all_classes">RESET ME</a>
```

Comment: try to use `$('.test').removeClass('testclass-active').addClass('testclass');` instead of using two lines.